# Seaborn Barplot: Heterogeneous groups of bars

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, bar-chart

I'm using seaborn to plot the results of different algorithms.
I want to distinguish both the different algorithms as well as their classification ("group").
The problem is that not all algorithms are in all groups, so when I use group as `hue`, I get a lot of blank space:

```py
import seaborn as sns
group = ['Simple', 'Simple', 'Complex', 'Complex', 'Cool']
alg = ['Alg 1', 'Alg 2', 'Alg 3', 'Alg 4', 'Alg 2']
results = [i+1 for i in range(len(group))]
sns.barplot(group, results, hue=alg)
```

[image: barplot]

As you can see, seaborn makes space for bars from all algorithms to be in all groups, leading to lots of blank space.
How can I avoid that?
I do want to show the different groups on the x-axis and distinguish the different algorithms by color/style.
Algorithms my occur in multiple but not all groups.
But I just want space for 2 bars in "Simple" and "Complex" and just for 1 in "Cool".
Any solutions with pure `matplotlib` are also welcome; it doesn't need to be seaborn. I'd like to keep the seaborn color palette though.

Comment: Is your question solved now? Or is something still unclear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be a standard way to create this type of grouped barplot. The following code creates a list of positions for the bars, their colors, and lists for the labels and their positions.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib.patches import Patch

group = ['Simple', 'Simple', 'Complex', 'Complex', 'Cool']
alg = ['Alg 1', 'Alg 2', 'Alg 3', 'Alg 4', 'Alg 2']
colors = plt.cm.tab10.colors
alg_cat = pd.Categorical(alg)
alg_colors = [colors[c] for c in alg_cat.codes]

results = [i + 1 for i in range(len(group))]

dist_groups = 0.4 # distance between successive groups
pos = (np.array([0] + [g1 != g2 for g1, g2 in zip(group[:-1], group[1:])]) * dist_groups + 1).cumsum()
labels = [g1 for g1, g2 in zip(group[:-1], group[1:]) if g1 != g2] + group[-1:]
label_pos = [sum([p for g, p in zip(group, pos) if g == label]) / len([1 for g in group if g == label])
             for label in labels]
plt.bar(pos, results, color=alg_colors)
plt.xticks(label_pos, labels)
handles = [Patch(color=colors[c], label=lab) for c, lab in enumerate(alg_cat.categories)]
plt.legend(handles=handles)
plt.show()
```

[image: resulting plot]

Answer (score 1):

While one could handle this case completely within `matplotlib` and `numpy`, I've solved it via `pandas`. The reason being that you need to figure out a way to do the categorical groupings correctly, and this is one of the main advantages in `pandas`.

So what I did, essentially, is create a DataFrame from your data, which is then grouped by - obviously - the `group` category. While iterating over each enumerated category with index `i=0,1,2,..`, we create a set of `ax.bar()` plots, each confined to the interval `[i-0.5, i+0,5]`. The colours are taken from the seaborn colormap, as requested, and are then also used in the end to create a custom legend.

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

group = ['Simple', 'Simple', 'Complex', 'Complex', 'Cool']
alg = ['Alg 1', 'Alg 2', 'Alg 3', 'Alg 4', 'Alg 2']
results = [i+1 for i in range(len(group))]

df = pd.DataFrame({'group':group, 'alg':alg, 'results':results})

## this next line is only required if you have a specific order in mind;
#  else, the .groupby() method will sort alphabetically!
df['group'] = pd.Categorical(df['group'], ["Simple", "Complex", "Cool"])

## choose the desired seaborn color palette here:
palette = sns.color_palette("Paired", len(alg))
labels, levels = pd.factorize(df['alg'])
df['color'] = [palette[l] for l in labels]

gdf = df.groupby('group')

fig,ax=plt.subplots(figsize=(5,3))  

xt = []
xtl = []

min_width = 1/max([len(item) for (key,item) in gdf])


for i,(key,item) in enumerate(gdf):
    xt.append(i)
    xtl.append(key)

    ## for each enumerated group, we need to create the proper x-scale placement
    #  such that each bar plot is centered around " i "
    #  i.e. two bars near " i = 0 " will be placed at [-0.25, 0.25] with widths of 0.5
    #  so that they won't collide with bars near " i = 1 "
    #  which themselves are placed at [0.75 1.25] 
    rel = np.linspace(0,1,len(item)+1)[:-1]
    rel -= rel.mean() 
    rel +=i

    w = 1/(len(item))
    ## note that the entire interval width (i.e. from i-0.5 to i+0.5) will be filled with the bars,
    #  meaning that the individual bar widths will vary depending on the number of bars.
    #  either adjust the bar width like this to add some whitespace:
    # w *= 0.9 
    ## or alternatively, you could use a fixed width instead:
    # w = 0.4
    ## or, by pre-evaluating the minimal required bar width:
    # w = min_width

    ax.bar(rel,item['results'].values,alpha=1,width=w,color=item['color'])

leg = []
for i,l in enumerate(levels):
    p = mpatches.Patch(color=palette[i], label=l)
    leg.append(p)
ax.legend(handles=leg)

ax.set_xticks(xt)
ax.set_xticklabels(xtl)
ax.grid()
plt.show()
```

The result (using `sns.color_palette("Paired")` and `w=1/len(item)`) then looks like this:

[image: nice bar plot]