# ValueError: The lengths of the data (3) and the error 5 do not match

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

i am plotting data in seaborn with this simple code below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['A','car',10,1],
                   ['A','plane',15,1],
                   ['A','bike',25,3],
                   ['B','plane',20,2],
                   ['C','bike',30,3]], 
                  columns = ['x','type','y', 'y_err']) 


print(df)


fig, axes = plt.subplots(figsize=(5, 5))

sns.set_theme(style="darkgrid")
 
g = sns.barplot(
      ax = axes, data=df,
      x="x", y='y', hue="type",
      palette="dark", alpha=.6 
)
```

And this is the output

[image: this is the output]

I got the problem when i try to insert custom error bar, adding `yerr=df['y_err']` in sns.barplot function.
The problem is:

```
ValueError: The lengths of the data (3) and the error 5 do not match
```

I am using seaborn because i have the need to plot different number of bars based on the particular x as in the example above.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without `seaborn` if you `pivot` your data as needed:

```
data = df.pivot("x", "type", "y")
errors = df.pivot("x", "type", "y_err")

data.plot.bar(yerr=errors)
```

###### Output:

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to center bars? For example green bar on the second tick and the blue one on the third tick are decentralised

Comment: They are per the first full group or the column names. Blue (bike) is the left-most in each group. You can't have different centres for each group.

Comment: So there is no way to centralise them? Not even with other approaches?

Comment: @Alessandro See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65141953/seaborn-barplot-heterogeneous-groups-of-bars

Comment: @Alessandro - Not saying there isn't. But if I knew one, I would've edited my answer.

Comment: @JohanC where can i found palette to change colors in your solution?

Comment: It is matplotlib's standard 'tab10' colormap. To use in seaborn: `sns.barplot(...., palette="dark", saturation=1)`